# PHP, validate user submitted URL with particular domain

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

I'm trying to validate a URL using a Regex with PHP. 
I need a pattern that considers valid:

- a well formed URL;
- http://www.domain.PF (this PF is very imporant, no other extension is valid);
- https://www.domain.PF
- ftp://...;
- domain.PF;
- www.domain.PF;

Any other is not valid, so you can't have ssh://, a .com domain, etc.

I tried the following pattern:

```
/(((http|ftp|https):\/{2})+(([0-9a-z_-]+\.)+(pf)(:[0-9]+)?((\/([~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@\.\/_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))\b/imuS
```

but I've lost many hours (and hairs) trying to make it work the way I need it to work.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Use http://www.php.net/parse_url, it tells many information about an url, including scheme, host..

Answer (score 2):

There is **[parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)** function in php.

Then it will be much easier to validate the `scheme` and `host` of the result of `parse_url`.

Comment: Problem is it failed in some cases: I tried it but it isn't perfect

Comment: @3000 It failed means that is not a well formed URL.

Comment: it means that parse_url is not perfect: it doesn't work if the protocol is not specified. The user can submit domain.pf too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
/((https?|ftp):\/\/.)?(www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\.pf/i
```

I am not sure whether this is the best solution.

Comment: which url did this expression fail? Can u please share? If you want to match _ and -. you may add it to character class.

Comment: My suspect is JS and PHP regexp aren't the same: maybe this works with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

^((http|ftp)[s]?://)?([\w-*/.]+)(.pf)([\w-*/.\&\%\$+\?]+)?$

Handles everything requested, unless I interpret the question wrong.
Test here: http://www.cuneytyilmaz.com/prog/jrx/ Please, do tick case insensitive.

**to implement in php use** /^((http|ftp)[s]?://)?([\w-*/.]+)(.pf)([\w-*/.\&\%\$+\?]+)?$/i

Comment: Thanks, somehow the escaped chars became unescaped when posting :)

Comment: In what sense, could you please be more specific? I could have it fixed in a matter of minutes I reckon

Comment: I updated my answer since I discovered I overlooked some details in the requirements. You can retest the regex and see that it will work. Should you need to add more special characters, please submit them here and I'll update the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way of doing what you want, granted it doesn't use regular expressions, but it is easier to maintain and uses native php functions for that reason:

```
<?php
function isValidPFurl($url) {
    if (strpos($url, "://" ) === false) {
        $url = 'http://' . $url;
    }
    $valid = filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
    if ($valid !== false) {
        $parsed = parse_url($valid);
        $host = $parsed['host'];
        $scheme = $parsed['scheme'];
        $valid = false;
        switch($scheme) {
            case 'ftp':
            case 'http':
            case 'https':
                $p = explode(".", $host);
                if ($p[sizeof($p) - 1] == 'pf') {
                    $valid = true;
                }
                break;
            default:
                $valid = false;
        }
    }
    return $valid;
}

$testUrls = array(
"http://example.pf/",
"example.pf",
"www.example.pf",
"ftp://example.pf",
"https://example.pf",
"ssl://example.pf"
);
foreach ($testUrls as $url) {
    echo "is $url valid? ", (int) isValidPFurl($url), "\n";
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for www.domain.pf and domain.pf (they return 0), while it is ok for http://...

Comment: I've fixed that now - if no scheme/protocol is in the url, it'll prepend "http://" for parse_url

Comment: Hehe, I can't explain why but this solution is not acceptable. I thank you very much for the effort, anyway.   :-)

Answer (score -1):

As per your need, you have to try this

```
 <?php
        $regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME
        $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass
        $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,4})"; // Host or IP
        $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port
        $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path
        $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query
        $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor
    ?>
```